# CefSharp 55.0 in VB.Net - Display the url when Document has loaded

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, cefsharp

I'm experimenting with the CefSharp browser for the first time with a WinForm (VB.NET) for a simple browser app I'm working on. There's only one thing that has been bothering me though...

In the past, I have used the stock VB/VS Browser control, and it has worked fine except the fact you have to mess with Emulation modes in the registry to get it to emulate as IE11. The VB/VS Browser control had a `DocumentCompleted` event that would run an action once the document/webpage had loaded. Namely, I have used this event to set the text of a TextBox to the browser's current URL.

However, I can't seem to find the equivalent (if there even *is* one) with CefSharp. Does anyone know how to do this with CefSharp?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: AddressChanged event.

Comment: @amaitland: would it be possible to provide the code?

Comment: I only write C#

Comment: There are plenty of examples https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/BrowserForm.cs

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I'm having a similar issue, did anyone ever figure this out in vb? I've been basing my code from the link above but lines 29 to 33 don't work when converted over from c#. I've tried using `WebChromiumBrowser.GetBrowser.FocusedFrame.Url` and similar in the AddressChanged Event but it fails